# How to use a mixin in React v16 ES6/ES7

Tags: reactjs, reactfire

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/blob/454ba395f260d82ad163e2d54a6e8fcd59073c97/docs/quickstart.md#4-add-the-reactfiremixin) for ReactFire, the way to use it is by adding a mixin to the component.

Mixins are not the way to go, HoC or Decorators should be used instead

So I wanted to create a Decorators, although the only way I found to use mixins is through `React.creatClass()`, which is deprecated and not even available in the latest React version.

How can I use a mixin with the latest version (v16.0)?

Or is there another way to use the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a long discussion on this here: 
https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/issues/38

You may also want to check out some alternative to ReactFire, like [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base)